# PostgreSQL version in connection string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-connection

I have two versions of postgresql installed, 9.4 and 9.5. I am using npm's [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) to connect to the server using a postgres connection string. From CLI, I can connect to 9.5 by using the `--cluter` option like so: `psql --cluster 9.5/main`. In postgres' [documentation for the connection string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS), they show one of the querystring parameters you can use is `options`:

> `options` - Adds command-line options to send to the server at run-time

I realize this means configuration parameters for the server, not the client. Nonetheless, I tried constructing the connection string and including the cluster option to connect to 9.5:

`postgres://user@localhost/db_name?options=--cluster%3D9.5%2Fmain`

And sure enough I get: `psql: FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "cluster"`

Okay, no surprise there. However, I can't seem to connect to 9.5 no matter what I do. I even have the environment variable `PGCLUSTER` set to the appropriate version string, however I think this is only read from CLI (ie: not when the server is connected to via unix socket or host).

What is the easiest way to connect to the 9.5 server instead of 9.4 from a script connecting to the server via `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to find the port that the 9.5 server is running on. In my case, 9.4 was running on port 5432 whereas 9.5 was running on **5433**. This is a simple change to the connection string:

`postgres://user:pass@localhost:5433/db_name`